# Arrays of arrays with distinct attributes

Tags: ruby

I have a array of arrays like this

```
array = [[Sat, 01 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Sat, 01 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 05 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 06 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 06 Jul 2017, 18.0],
         [Fri, 07 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 12 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 13 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Fri, 14 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 19 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 20 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Fri, 21 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 26 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 27 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Fri, 28 Jul 2017, 2.0]]
```

I want to convert this array like this

```
array = [[Sat, 01 Jul 2017, 4.0],
         [Wed, 05 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 06 Jul 2017, 20.0],
         [Fri, 07 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 12 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 13 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Fri, 14 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 19 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 20 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Fri, 21 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Wed, 26 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Thu, 27 Jul 2017, 2.0],
         [Fri, 28 Jul 2017, 2.0]]
```

Comment: Not sure what needs to be done. Do you want to sort array by date?

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is `Sat, 01 Jul 2017` a date object or a string? If the latter please add quotes.I assume you wish to remove duplicates for each day, but whatever your objective, you should state it rather than just use an example to try to infer it.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.group_by(&:first).map do |k, v|
  [k, v.reduce(0) { |memo, (_, v)| memo + v }]
end
```

or

```
array.map(&:dup)
     .group_by(&:shift)
     .map { |k, v| [k, v.flatten.reduce(&:+)] }
```

or

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k, v), acc|
  acc[k] += v
end.to_a
```

Comment: As the array appears to be sorted by date, `chunk` or `slice_when` may be more descriptive than `group_by`.

Comment: Thanks you so much @mudasobwa